# Accessing Certain Element in 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

edit: Feeling dumb. Change for loop start to 1 instead of 0. Thanks!

sorry for the newbie question.

So let's assume I have a 2 dimensional array of type String. It is 5x5. The first element in every row is a code, while the other 4 are numbers only.

For example,
{ABC1, 123, 456, 789, 123}
{DEF2, 133, 123, 241, 123}
etc.

I know how to navigate the array by using nested for loops by doing

```
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        ...
     }
}
```

But how would I skip the first element in every row, only get the numeric values so I can cast them to int/double and add them?

Thanks.

Comment: Change the part of the code which tells it to start at the first element.

Comment: Holy **** am I stupid. Thanks @shmosel what a stupid mistake. Got to take a break sometimes, eh? Haha.